# Stationary distribution for a Markov Chain on an uncountable space

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, ergodic-theory

Suppose $X_n$ is a Markov chain on an uncountable state space $\Omega$ (We can assume $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$), and suppose that $X_n$ is irreducible, aperiodic and Harris recurrent.

What are the extra conditions that will guarantee that $X_n$ has a stationary distribution $\pi$?

In the discrete case, every chain with these conditions has a (unique) stationary distribution, but for the uncountable case I am struggling to find a reference.

Comment: This note is helpful by Martin Hairer(http://www.hairer.org/notes/Markov.pdf) and (http://www.hairer.org/notes/Convergence.pdf) and (http://www.hairer.org/papers/harris.pdf)